# Any way to remove the need for so many META tags?

Tags: meta-tags, bandwidth

This is a part of what is in the `<head>` of every single page, and is therefore downloaded by the user every single time they load a page - most of them don't even affect browsers:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="long list of keywords here" />
<meta name="description" content="Site's description here" />
<meta name="language" content="en_uk" />
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow" />
<meta name="application-name" content="Site name" />
<meta name="msapplication-tooltip" content="Site description" />
<meta name="msapplication-starturl" content="http://example.com/" />
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#004000" />
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Do something;action-uri=http://example.com/page1;icon-uri=http://example.com/img/icon/action1.ico" />
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Do something;action-uri=http://example.com/page2;icon-uri=http://example.com/img/icon/action2.ico" />
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Do something;action-uri=http://example.com/page3;icon-uri=http://example.com/img/icon/action3.ico" />
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Do something;action-uri=http://example.com/page4;icon-uri=http://example.com/img/icon/action4.ico" />
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Do something;action-uri=http://example.com/page5;icon-uri=http://example.com/img/icon/action5.ico" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Site name (Again!)" />
<meta property="og:type" content="game" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/img/ads/square3.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site name (AGAIN!)" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="FB UID" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Site descripion (AGAIN!)" />
```

As you can see there's even some redundant properties because different scrapers use different things. And that's without any Google Plus1 button, or any other sharing site besides Facebook...

Is there any way to tidy this up? Maybe I could have it so that they only appear on the frontpage and then is there any way to tell anything that actually wants the meta info that it can be found there?

Comment: you can make function of those which are common across all page and  cal it

Comment: @NullPointer That's what I already do: `<?php require("generic/pagehead.php"); ?>`. The point of this question is for the user to not have to download these tags every single time they load a page - an average user loads around a thousand pages a day on this game...

Comment: If you serve pages with compression, all this will slim down quite nicely.

Comment: Already do, but it still feels redundant.

Comment: I doubt that this actually is a significant amount of traffic compared to what else you do, you serve up entire pages each page hit, which these meta-tags are probably only a small portion of. You probably have a lot of images on your site, which means you will have a lot of bandwidth expended on that. Honestly, I don't think this is where you should be looking if you want to decrease bandwidth usage.

Comment: if you are using any meta tag except description check this http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html

Comment: The thing is, it may not seem like much, but I get about 2 million pageloads every day. The whole collection of META tags is about 2kB long. That's a total of 4GB of extra bandwidth every day that is completely useless to all except the scrapers that use it. Put another way, that's about 120GB every month. This is why I'm looking for a way to not need those elements on every page.